# update a dataTable table based on another Filtered dataTable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using dataTable library to display data that I get from the database, everything is working fine here is how the table looks like:

[image]

This table gets updated automatically with the filters on the top, for example when I choose, a specific customer, the table gets filtered( this is taken care of by dataTable), for example when I choose the DATASTREAM CUSTOMER, it shows me only the rows related to that customer:[image]

However, I am creating another table that uses the current filtered data in the first table. For example:

The **No. of requests** in the new table is basically the number of rows in the updated table.

[image]

In the beginning, the **no. of requests** in the second table is correct as I have 9 rows.

However, when I use the filter, the customer filter, for example, the **no. of requests** remains the same and doesn't change.

[image]

How to dynamically change the values of the second table according to the first table, should I use an even or something? Or, where should I insert the code that generates the HTML of the second table?

Here is my code:

```js
var PoCTableDivHTML = makePoCTableHTML (PoCDataFromAJAXQuery); // HTML from the first table 

$('#PoCTableDivID').html(PoCTableDivHTML);  // update the div with HTML

// apply the filters and attach them to the selectors 
$('#CurrentActiveViewPoCTable').dataTable().columnFilter({
   aoColumns: [ null,null, {  sSelector: "#customerSelect", type:"select" }, null , null ,null,null,null,null,null,{  sSelector: "#CUSelect", type:"select" },{  sSelector: "#DomainSelect", type:"select" },{  sSelector: "#SubDomainSelect", type:"select" }]
            
  });

 
 
// get the first table    
var PoC_Table = document.getElementById('CurrentActiveViewPoCTable');

//gets rows of the first table
var rowLength = PoC_Table.rows.length;

var AnalysisTableDivhTML = makeAnalysisTableHTML(rowLength);// generate the html for the second table 

$('#PoC_AnalyisisTableDivID').html(AnalysisTableDivhTML);  // attach the second table html to its div
$('#CurrentActiveViewPoC_AnalysisTable').dataTable(); // call data table
```

And here is the function that takes the data from the first HTML table and updates the second table:

```js
unction makeAnalysisTableHTML (NoOFrowTest)
{
 var analysisTableHTML;
 // add the table ID and the header 
 analysisTableHTML= '<table id="CurrentActiveViewPoC_AnalysisTable"  style="float:left;" class="display dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">\
 <thead style="display:none;">\
  <tr>\
   <th> property  </th>\
   <th> value </th>\
  </tr>\
 </thead>';
 
 // add the footer 
 analysisTableHTML += 
 '<tfoot style="display:none;">\
  <tr>\
   <th> property  </th>\
   <th> value </th>\
  </tr>\
 </tfoot>';
 
 // add the body of the table 
 analysisTableHTML += 
 '<tbody>\
  <tr>';
  analysisTableHTML +=  '<td>'+  "no. of requests"  +'</td>';
  analysisTableHTML +=  '<td>' + NoOFrowTest +'</td>';
  analysisTableHTML +=
  '</tr>\
  <tr>\
   <td> No. of approved ongoing PoC </td>\
   <td> update later </td>\
  </tr>\
 </tbody></table>';
 
 return analysisTableHTML;
 
 
}
```

Comment: Your code snippets are not working.

Comment: these are just functions and part of the code, I didn't add the html